# HPE Proliant Gen10 Stack Fault Exception during PXE boot with UEFI

Tags: pxe-boot, uefi, hpe

I am trying to pxe boot a HPE Proliant Gen10 using UEFI BIOS with RHEL (have tried both 7 and 8) and am getting a stack fault exception after the server receives the first boot file (shimx64.efi):

HPE ProLiant System BIOS U32 v2.42 (01/23/2021)
(C) Copyright 1982-2021 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP
Early system initialization, please wait...

iLO 5 IPv4:
iLO 5 IPv6:

iLO 5 IPv4: (redacted)
iLO 5 IPv6: (redacted)

2%: System Chipset Initialization
4%: UPI Link Initialization - Start
5%: UPI Link Initialization - Complete
7%: Early Processor Initialization
9%: Memory Initialization - Start
10%:   11%:   13%:   14%:   15%:   21%: Memory Initialization - Complete
25%: SMBIOS Table Initialization
28%: USB Controller Initialization
31%: Chipset Root Ports Initialization
35%: HPE SmartMemory Initialization
38%: System Security Initialization
42%: iLO Embedded Health Initialization
45%: ACPI Table Initialization
49%: BIOS Configuration Initialization
L  55%: Early PCI Initialization - Start
62%: Early PCI Initialization - Complete
73%: Switching console output to Primary Video. Please wait...

[=3h

[=3h
[01;01

[=3h

[=3h

[=3h

[=3h

(C) Copyright 1982-2021 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP
HPE ProLiant DL360 Gen10
System ROM Version: U32 v2.42 (01/23/2021)
Serial Number: (redacted)

Installed System Memory: 384 GB, Available System Memory: 384 GB

2 Processor(s) detected, 40 total cores enabled, Hyperthreading is enabled
Proc 1: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248 CPU @ 2.50GHz
Proc 2: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248 CPU @ 2.50GHz
UPI Speed: 10.4 GT/s

Workload Profile: I/O Throughput
Power Regulator Mode: Dynamic Power Savings
Advanced Memory Protection Mode: Fast Fault Tolerant Memory (ADDDC)
Boot Mode: UEFI
HPE SmartMemory authenticated in all populated DIMM slots.

For access via BIOS Serial Console:
Press 'ESC+9' for System Utilities
Press 'ESC+0' for Intelligent Provisioning
Press 'ESC+!' for One-Time Boot Menu
Press 'ESC+@' for Network Boot

Starting required devices. Please wait, this may take a few moments....

> > Booting Embedded FlexibleLOM 1 Port 1 : HPE Eth 10/25Gb 2p 640FLR-SFP28 Adptr - NIC (PXE IPv4)

> > Start PXE over IPv4.
> > Station IP address is (redacted)

Server IP address is (redacted)
NBP filename is bootloader/pxe.boot.host/image
NBP filesize is 1877432 Bytes
Downloading NBP file...

NBP file downloaded successfully.

X64 Exception Type 0x0C - Stack Fault Exception

RCX=0000000000000001 DX=0000000036E13971 R8=00000000A0D29060 R9=000000007B2314F0
RSP=000000007B2315F8 BP=AFAFAFAFAFAFAFAF AX=0000000000000000 BX=000000003932D000
R10=000000007B231558 11=9A02503F3EB2EC9E 12=0000000000000000 13=0000000000000040
R14=00000000982470C0 15=0000000000000001 SI=000000009ED79018 DI=0000000000000E40
CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=00000000A347B000 CR0=80000013 CR4=00000668 CR8=00000000
CS=00000038 DS=00000030 SS=00000030 ES=00000030 RFLAGS=00210286
MSR: 0x1D9 = 00004801, 0x345=000033C5, 0x1C9=00000004

LBRs From              To                From              To
01h  0000000036E0DE86->000000009A1D2174  0000000036E0E4C4->0000000036E0DE23
03h  0000000036E0E977->0000000036E0E4C4  000000007B0FB7AB->0000000036E0E948
05h  000000007B0FB82C->000000007B0FB85E  000000007B0FB738->000000007B0FB80C
07h  000000007B0FB73D->000000007B0FB71B  000000007B0FB863->000000007B0FB73A
09h  000000007B0FB868->000000007B0FB860  000000007B0FB844->000000007B0FB864
0Bh  000000007B0FB738->000000007B0FB80C  000000007B0FB73D->000000007B0FB71B
0Dh  000000007B0FB863->000000007B0FB73A  000000007B0FB868->000000007B0FB860
0Fh  000000007B0FB844->000000007B0FB864  000000009A1D217F->000000009FBAD940

CALL ImageBase        ImageName+Offset
00h  0000000000000000 No Image Information
01h  0000000000000000 No Image Information

CALL ImageBase        ImageName+Offset

STACK   00h      04h      08h      0Ch      10h      14h      18h      1Ch
RSP+00h 9EFC7818 9A08AB98 9EFBF56D 9EFC7818 00000000 9ED79018 00000000 4CF5B200
RSP+20h 9EFC1B9B 4CF5B200 733AA782 7B231710 982470C0 365CA000 00000040 7B109960
RSP+40h 733A904F 3932D000 365CA000 7331C340 733A787F 734C8EE5 7340ADE0 734C8F55
RSP+60h 7331E4A8 734C84A0 73450911 7331C048 7331E4A0 7B231800 7331C320 9EFBAC48
RSP+80h 7331E520 7B231840 00000001 7331E420 7B231870 734500AB 7331C048 7331E500
RSP+A0h 9EFBAC48 73450A83 7331C288 7331E580 734500AB 7331C288 7331E640 00000000
RSP+C0h 73450EC5 7331E5E0 7344CF6E 73324300 7331E640 7331E5E0 73438071 73325580
RSP+E0h 7331E640 73324300 7331EA52 7331EA40 00000000 734382B2 73325580 00000000

Answer (score 0):

you are not booting a Shim file (shimx64.efi)

RHEL shim file is called `BOOTX64.EFI` and is about `1.2MB`

RHEL grub file is called `grubx64.efi` and is about `1.8MB`

From your Log considering the size of the NBP transfer (NBP filesize is 1877432 Bytes) I think you are booting `grubx64.efi` instead of `BOOTX64.EFI`

EDIT 1:

If after booting the correct `BOOTX64.EFI` you are still getting the same exception try booting the 64 bit version of `bootmgfw.efi` (Microsoft UEFI Boot Manager)

If it boots correctly (even when will surely fail trying to load the BCD) that means your firmware does not implement a UEFI conformant environment and fails when loading a shim

If it also fails booting you are probably not really booting in UEFI mode or your firmware is definitely buggy.

EDIT 2:

you could also run a memory test and see if your RAM is OK...

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I've fixed that and am booting BOOTX64.EFI.  Same exception.  It receives BOOTX64, then requests grubx64.efi, and exception occurs.

Comment: See my edit ...

Comment: Appreciate the help, but the Microsoft UEFI Boot Manager is not available in my test environment.  I'll try to pursue this with the vendor and their firmware.

Comment: See my Edit 2 ...